# How Can I Arrive at the Fee-Adjusted APR, Accounting for Balance Transfer Fee (But Not Inflation)?

Tags: finance

I'm trying to figure out the fee-adjusted interest rate paid when incurring a balance transfer fee on a loan, not accounting for inflation.

If the APR is 4%, the loan 5000, the transfer 2% and you pay it off in 200 days (54.8% of the year when rounded to 2 decimals), I see it this way:
(APR: 4%  Loan: 5,000  Transfer fee: 2%  Days: 200)

**Present Value**: 4,900  (Loan - transfer fee %)
**Future Value**: 5,109.589041095890411 (loan * ( APR * (200/365) ) )
**Real Rate Over 200 Days**: 4.2773273693039%  ( (FV - PV) / PV )
**Real Rate Over 365 days**: 7.806122448979618% ( ( (FV - PV) / PV ) * (365/200) )

Is there something missing and if so, what?

Comment: If *real* does not mean *adjusted for inflation*, does it just mean *including fee*? Also 200 is not 5.48% of the year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would expect the amount to be paid after 200 days to be $$5000 \times 1.04^{200/365} \approx 5108.617$$ so the effective interest rate including fees over 200 days to be $$\frac{5108.617}{5000\times 0.98}-1 \approx  4.2575\%$$ and the annualised effective interest rate including fees to be $$\left(\frac{5108.617}{5000\times 0.98}\right)^{365/200}-1 \approx 7.9060\%$$
and these numbers are close to but not the same as yours.